# Degree centrality on projected graph neo4j. Optimal way to create projected graph

Tags: neo4j, graph-algorithm

I am trying out the graph algorithm [Degree](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-algorithms/current/algorithms/degree-centrality/).

My model has several node and relationship labels and one of which is "Entity" and lets call the other labels "Random".

What I want to create is a projection of the graph that basically removes all other nodes except "entity" but keeps the edges/relationships that would have been possible with the nodes.

e.g if we have `(e1:Entity) -> (:Random) -> (:Random) -> (e2:Entity)` then the result is `(e1) -> (e2)`

or

`(e1:Entity)-[*..5]-(e1:Entity)` gives us `(e1)--(e2)`

Where the path between the two entities does not have an Entity between them.

The problem I have with my current cypher statement is that it seems to be slow or not returning what I am expecting. So I am wondering if I have missed something.

This is what I am currently using for creating the projection:

```
MATCH p = (start:Entity)-[*..5]-(end:Entity)
WHERE start.id <> end.id
WITH start, end, [n IN nodes(p) WHERE 'Entity' in labels(n) | n] as entities
WHERE size(entities) = 2
RETURN id(start) as source, id(end) as target
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use case (finding and testing all paths of up to length 5 that end in `Entity` nodes) is *inherently* expensive.

That being said, the following query should be somewhat faster.

- This query only tests the labels of interior path nodes.
- Since your query is non-directional, this query avoids label-testing the same path twice (via the `start.id > end.id` test).
- It avoids creating temporary node collections and evaluating their size.

  ```
  MATCH p = (start:Entity)-[*..5]-(end:Entity)
  WHERE start.id > end.id AND NONE(n IN NODES(p)[1..-1] WHERE 'Entity' in LABELS(n))
  RETURN ID(start) as source, ID(end) as target
  ```